# Using Siege to test https

Tags: load-testing, performance-testing

I am trying to use [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) to load test an https site and am getting SegFaults. I am using Siege 3.0.5 installed using the [siege homebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/siege.rb) (which has openssl support turned on) on OS X Mavericks.

HTTP works fine:

```
$ siege http://www.google.com
** SIEGE 3.0.5
** Preparing 15 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...
HTTP/1.1 302   0.67 secs:     261 bytes ==> GET  /
HTTP/1.1 302   1.02 secs:     261 bytes ==> GET  /
HTTP/1.1 200   0.78 secs:   14409 bytes ==> GET  /?gws_rd=cr&ei=H3TMUrb8BojolAXvrYCwBA
```

But HTTPS segfaults (I have tested other sites than google and get the same error)

```
$ siege https://www.google.com
** SIEGE 3.0.5
** Preparing 15 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...
[1]    5789 segmentation fault  siege https://www.google.com
```

Comment: Hey Joseph, what's the output of `otool -L $(which siege)`? I'm not in front of a Mac right now, so I can only test it on my linux box. This is the output that I get from `ldd $(which siege)`: http://sprunge.us/hbMO . You should have something similar, but not exactly the same.

Comment: Google shows a lot of SegFault issues with Siege on different OSes. Would running Siege from a virtual machine be an option?

Comment: Here's some more detailed info on my friend's mac, where `siege https://www.google.com` does work: https://gist.github.com/shurane/8307728/raw/59e3406d1aca245cfa6b409a7cc16781e569316f/terminal.txt

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but I think I have worked out what the problem is (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a bug. I am using siege behind a proxy. I have the proxy settings in my `.siegerc` file. When I remove the proxy settings then `siege https://www.google.com` works.

Comment: What settings did you remove?

Comment: @jefffabiny proxy-host and proxy-port